# Multiple Full Defense Actions in the same Combat Turn?

Tags: actions, shadowrun-sr5, defense

The "Full Defense" Interrupt Action allows a character to decrease their Initiative Score by 10, and the add their Willpower to their defense rolls for the remainder of the Combat Turn.  However, the section of the core rulebook describing this action is unclear on whether it may be performed more than once in the same Combat Turn.  The relevant section of the rule is

> This bonus is also cumulative with other Interrupt Actions.

It is unclear whether:

1. The word "other" refers to Interrupt Actions that are not Full Defense (so any of the others, such as Block, Parry, etc.).  Therefore, a character is limited to one Full Defense action per Combat Turn.
2. The word "other" simply refers to Interrupt Actions that are not this specific action, which would allow for other Full Defense actions to be performed and stack their bonuses.

Is there another section of rules clarifying this, or is this just an unclear area that has to be adjudicated by the GM?

Answer (score 1):

## Kind of.

Adopting a Full Defense lasts for the entire Combat Turn, not just the rest of your turn; the bonus falls off when initiative is rolled for the next Combat Turn. Since Full Defense doesn't stack with itself, there's not a reason to perform it again.

#### However!

There are multiple types of Full Defense, that act on different "planes" of combat. For example, if one were a technomancer who had the misfortune of being attacked by gangers AND a xenosapient AI at the same time, they could (and possibly should!) go on both Full Defense and Full Matrix Defense, each one decreasing their initiative score by 10.

Comment: Where is it stated that Full Defense does not stack with itself?